# Perl connection to Google Cloud MySQL Not working

Tags: perl, unix, ssl, dbi

A MySQL server was setup in Google Cloud and SSL was enabled, however when trying to connect it gives this error

```
SSL connection error: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. The name in the certificate does  at trial.pl line 24.
```

This is the error I am seeing, I downloaded the certificates directly from the GCP website.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "raw_data";
my $database_url = "GCP_IP";
my $userid = "GCP_username";
my $password = "GCP_pass";
my $table = "raw_data_test";

my $key = "client-key.pem";
my $cert = "client-cert.pem";
my $ca = "server-ca.pem";

my $ssl = "mysql_ssl=1;mysql_ssl_client_key=$key;mysql_ssl_client_cert=$cert;mysql_ssl_ca_file=$ca";

my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database:$database_url;$ssl";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password) or die $DBI::errstr;

print("IT WORKS\n");
```

my code is exactly as above (I omitted the identifying information about the server)

When the ssl string is removed from the dsn it connects without issue because SSL is not fully enforced. I run the code in the directory where the certs are. So is there something wrong with my code? Or is this something to do GCP?

Additionally, if I use a mysql command directly in terminal to connect to the database with the certs/keys, it connects without error. I am not sure how to narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: Try using the full path instead of just the file name. Relying on the current directory would be a security risk.

Comment: Thanks, this is just a test script, full paths are used the in the actual implementation. It doesn't get rid of the error either.

Comment: Verify permission on certificate files, potentially if permission is too permissive then software might decide that such certificate can be exploited and refuse to use it.